# Python pandas dataframe write \n as text to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

What I would like is to write the sentence "hello \n world\n." in a cell as it is, without "\n" being considered end of line, such that when I open it in a text editor I could see exactly "hello \n world\n.". How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want this? This will confuse both humans and programs. CSV files allow for quoted fields with newlines and so does Pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_string':['hello \n world! \n', 'hello \nworld!\n']})


df = df.stack().str.replace('\n', '\\n', regex=True).unstack()


df.to_csv('hi.csv')
```

Output text:

```
,full_string
0,hello \n world! \n
1,hello \nworld!\n
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python backslash is used as escape character. This means that inside string if you dont want to use special character such as newline character, you have put the backslash in front.

```
print("Hello \nWorld")
-> Hello
   World

print("Hello \\nWorld")
-> Hello \nWorld
```